# Is vulkan.hpp documentation wrong about initializing default dynamic dispatcher?

Tags: vulkan

To be clear I installed latest version of LunarG's SDK for windows and I updated my nVidia drivers for the latest ones, still I am getting complains from compiler that `no instance of overloaded function:"vk::DispatchLoaderDynamic::init" matches the argument list`, when trying to call:

`VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init();`

is the documentation wrong?

I beleive I am using the necessary macros:
In header:

`#define VULKAN_HPP_DISPATCH_LOADER_DYNAMIC 1`

In cpp file then:

`VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCH_LOADER_DYNAMIC_STORAGE`

But to be onest in vulkan.hpp I do not see any such a method without args (just inits with arguments).

Also other methods:

```
static vk::DispatchLoaderDynamic _loader;

const PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr vkGetInstanceProcAddr =
  _loader.getProcAddress<PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr>("vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(vkGetInstanceProcAddr);

const vk::Instance instance = vk::createInstance(createInfo);
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(instance);

const vk::Device device = gpu.createDevice(createInfo);
VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(device);
```

work fine for me.

Just I am not sure then if I init the default dynamic loader as if I try to use Vulkan calls in other dll (within same process) the adresses to vulkan methods of `Dispatch const & d` are 0x0000... except vkCreateInstance and vkDestroyInstance (only these two have some values, so I do not get access violation calling them in other dll).